# How to import a jar file which is in a package?

Tags: java, jar

I have a jar file named [stdlib-package](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/code/), the **.class** files in this jar file are all in a **edu.princeton.cs.introcs** package

For example, I want to use one class named **StdDraw** from that jar file in my own codes

Say **E:\code** is my current working directory. like other conditions, I create a subdirectory **bin\edu\princeton\cs\introcs** to put **stdlib-package** in

Here is my codes:

```
package com.david.test;
import edu.princeton.cs.introcs.stdlib-package.*; // any problems here ?

public class DrawTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        StdDraw.line(0.5, 0.5, 1, 0.5);
    }
}
```

Then I put **DrawTest.java** in the **src\com\david\test**

To compile the **DrawTest.java**, I type the commands in command line:

```
javac -d bin -cp bin\edu\princeton\cs\introcs\stdlib-package.jar src\com\david\test\DrawTest.java
```

But it failed : package **edu.princeton.cs.introcs.stdlib_package** doesn't exist...

I searched for a lot of time, but haven't found the answer
Thanks for your help

**EDIT===**
@EJP's comment solves my question too.

Comment: For better experience in coding, use an IDE

Comment: The package is in the JAR file, not the other way around, and it's the package you want to import, not the JAR file. "I create a subdirectory bin\edu\princeton\cs\introcs to put stdlib-package in" Why? You don't need all that. Just put it in 'lib' like everybody else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should be all you need in code:

```
import edu.princeton.cs.introcs.*
```

Then you only need to make sure the jar is on your class path; it doesn't matter what the name of the jar is, or where it is.  If it is on your classpath, Java will load it, and use the location of the files within it.

Move the jar into a `lib` directory in your current directory, and do something like

```
javac -cp lib\stdlib-package.jar src\com\david\test\DrawTest.javac
```

Comment: thank you, but can you show me the command line codes for compiling ?

Answer (score 1):

Your import is wrong. There's no such package in that .jar file.

```
import edu.princeton.cs.introcs.*;
```

In general, however, that's a bad practice and you should really only import what you need:

```
import edu.princeton.cs.introcs.StdDraw;
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand that there is no package with 'stdlib-package' name.

If the fully qualified name of the class you are using is edu.princeton.cs.introcs.StdDraw, you can just import 'edu.princeton.cs.introcs.StdDraw'

```
     import edu.princeton.cs.introcs.StdDraw
```

If you want to load all the classes in that package

```
     import edu.princeton.cs.introcs.*
```